# Excel Add-In behavior with multiple open spreadsheets

Tags: excel, excel-addins

I have not been able to find an answer to this question. Maybe I'm using the wrong search terms.

If I have multiple spreadsheets open that use the same Excel Add-In does each spreadsheet get its own instance of the Add-In so that data saved in variables by the Add-In from one workbook are separate from data saved by the Add-In from another workbook?

Expect data stored to be separate.

Don

Comment: According to my observations. First of all, let's be clear with terms - there are Application, Add-ins, Workbook, Worsheets. Each instance of Application may host a number of workbooks, which, in turn, host worksheets.  As well, an instance of application hosts an instance of a add-in, so I may assume, that different instances of Application may host different instances of add-ins, despite the number of lower layer - Workbooks, Worksheets and so on. You may try to dig deeper using the `AddIn.progID` property, but I don't know how it works exactly.

Comment: I am asking about different workbooks in one application instance using the same Add-In.

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, below you can see a simple code in test_add_in which shows hosting process' id:

```
Option Explicit

Declare Function GetCurrentProcessId Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Sub test_addin_prodId()
Dim a As AddIn
Dim w As Workbook


On Error Resume Next
Set w = ActiveWorkbook
On Error GoTo 0

    If w Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "No workbook is active"
    Else
        Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Name
    End If

For Each a In Application.AddIns
    Debug.Print "Add-in name: " & a.Name & ", process Id: " & GetCurrentProcessId
Next

End Sub
```

And on a screenshot you may see the result in two different instances of an excel application:
[image]

I think, that this example may confirm my assumption regarding the fact that different instances of an Excel application host different instances of an add-in, which in turn, answers your question:

> each spreadsheet get its own instance of the Add-In so that data saved
> in variables by the Add-In from one workbook are separate from data
> saved by the Add-In from another workbook?

No, each workbook doesn't get an instance of an add-in, but each instance of an excel application does despite the number of open workbooks:

First application instance (on the right), two workbooks open:
[image]

Second application instance (on the left), no open workbooks:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Based on your input I created a test (which I should have done in the first place I guess). I created an add-in with a private long variable named counter and two public subs (showcounter and bumpcounter). Showcounter does a debug. Print of counter and bumpcounter adds 1 to counter. I then created a workbook that upon opening called showcounter and bumpcounter.  I saved the workbook as book1 and book2. Upon opening book1 the counter displayed as 0. I opened book2, without closing book1, and counter displayed as 1.